# An audio player that showcase a random song from playlist every 24h

Tags: php, javascript

The task is :

An audio player that showcase a random song from playlist every 24h.
The player is an wordpress plugin (Zoomsounds).
The shortcode to display it is [zoomsounds id="test"].
Playlist audio files are stored as posts.
After hours or research, I found some php code that can help:

```
$randomPosts = get_posts(array(
   'orderby' => 'rand',
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'tag' => $tag,
));
```

I have no coding experience. How can I integrate that code with the plugin so that it will display a random song every 24 hours ? Is it possible to wrap that function in shortcode ?

Comment: This sounds like it's specific to the plugin; you should ask Zoomsounds' support team.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do that by caching the page every 24h. Thank you!